# Nasm - Faulty win32n.inc doesn't reserve space for arrays in struct definitions?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

EDIT: The Win32n.inc from [link](http://rs1.szif.hu/~tomcat/win32/) cannot handle arrays. When searching for an .inc file get it from somewhere else! That should prevent these errors.

I found something in my win32n.inc (and all the others on the Internet) that seems a little odd:

`FLOATING_SAVE_AREA` is declared as:

```
STRUC FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
.ControlWord RESD 1
.StatusWord RESD 1
.TagWord RESD 1
.ErrorOffset RESD 1
.ErrorSelector RESD 1
.DataOffset RESD 1
.DataSelector RESD 1
.RegisterArea RESB 1
.Cr0NpxState RESD 1
ENDSTRUC
```

Which confuses me because the official declaration in winnt.h is:

```
typedef struct _FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
{
 DWORD      ControlWord;
 DWORD      StatusWord;
 DWORD      TagWord;
 DWORD      ErrorOffset;
 DWORD      ErrorSelector;
 DWORD      DataOffset;
 DWORD      DataSelector;
 BYTE       RegisterArea[80]; <----- this doesn't fit, does it?
 DWORD      Cr0NpxState;
} FLOATING_SAVE_AREA;
```

So why does my win32n.inc only reserves for 1 byte when it contains a 80 byte array? I know that another way to save an array is to only reserve memory for it's base address. But this also doesn't work here, since it reserves only memory for 1 byte and not 4 byte (size of an address).

So how do I handle this?

Comment: This indeed looks like a mistake.

Comment: You recently posted another question where the PE IMAGE_HEADER definition was weird, maybe you should get include files somewhere else or switch to a different compiler.

Comment: It's probably automatically generated and the program that automatically generates the include files doesn't handle arrays. It's unlikely whatever include files you're using are actually being seriously used by anyone so there's likely going to be a lot of undiscovered problems like this.

Comment: @RossRidge It makes sense when these files are automatically generated (and the generation is incorrect). Because I already switched my win32n.inc files multiple times. But every time they seem to be identical. So I will just change `RESB 1`to `RESD 1` and save the address of the array.

Comment: No, you need 80 bytes. `RESB 80` maybe?

Comment: @Anders yes, you are right.

Comment: This would be a better question if you said something about where exactly this copy came from.  It's just obviously wrong and easy to fix by hand, so the interesting part is that it's being distributed, and who wrote it in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes Here's where it's from: [link](http://rs1.szif.hu/~tomcat/win32/). I also got some copies out of a post on [link](www.rohitab.com) and [link](www.forum.nasm.us). All of these copies seem to be the same, so I think the users who uploaded them got them from the first link. Since all of the files were the same, I assumed it was an official .inc file. But now that I was told otherwise, I indeed found another version on [link](http://www.developertalk.de/assembler-unter-win32-tutorials/tutorials/t205-f72/).

Comment: please edit some of that into your question, in the first paragraph.  And IMO you should post the good version as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your .inc file seems to have been generated by a tool that does not understand arrays.

Replace `.RegisterArea RESB 1` [with `.RegisterArea RESB 80`](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.11.11).